# Consultas SELECT sin repetir ID DE IDENTIFICACION solo el resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es mi tabla:

```sql
SELECT nroent, fecha, nomentidad, convenio, tdoc, paciente, nompaciente, apellidos, nombres, sexo, recibo, autoriz, edad, f_nacimiento, cargo, empresa_temporal, carne,  procedi, nomprocedi, valor, copago, nro, diag, nom_diag, municipio, dpto, ccostos, nomcosto, cant, ledad, lmunicipio, lregimen, nropro, nro_hist, diag_prin, nroproc, entsub, dcto, consulta, ok,  paq, tarifa, bodega, lote, cum, fvence, prof_remitente, crips, examen, insumo, id, subentidad, fecha_adm, tipo_servi_despacho, prefijo, numero FROM db GROUP BY paciente
```

En esta consulta recibo esto:
Por seguridad cambio la identificación de la persona.

[image: Borro y hago cambios en la imagen por seguridad.]

**¿Que resultado busco?**

El resultado que busco es que la identificación solo aparezca una sola vez y que solo con ella itere lo que le corresponde.

```
1123456789 
------------------------------------- RESULADO UNO
------------------------------------- RESULTADO DOS
------------------------------------- RESULTADO DOS
ETC
```

Comment: Y donde queres que pase eso? las ide de consultas de bases de datos no hacen eso, muestran tablas como vienen los datos... y con un query no podes hacer eso. Eso lo tenes que hacer en el lugar donde vayas a mostrar tus datos...

Comment: No has probado de esta manera `SELECT DISTINCT paciente, nroent.... FROM db GROUP BY paciente,nombrepaciente`, poniendo a paciente al principio?

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. en donde??? en php?? y donde esta tu codigo php???

Comment: Prueba con `SELECT paciente FROM ( SELECT nroent, fecha, nomentidad, convenio, tdoc, paciente, nompaciente, apellidos, nombres, sexo, recibo, autoriz, edad, f_nacimiento, cargo, empresa_temporal, carne,  procedi, nomprocedi, valor, copago, nro, diag, nom_diag, municipio, dpto, ccostos, nomcosto, cant, ledad, lmunicipio, lregimen, nropro, nro_hist, diag_prin, nroproc, entsub, dcto, consulta, ok,  paq, tarifa, bodega, lote, cum, fvence, prof_remitente, crips, examen, insumo, id, subentidad, fecha_adm, tipo_servi_despacho, prefijo, numero FROM db GROUP BY paciente
 ) AS T GROUP BY (T.paciente)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Me permito socializar la respuesta de lo que deseaba para aquellos que como yo en su momento lo necesiten.

Suma valores y concatena todos los resultados por ID en una línea:

```sql
 SELECT nroent,
       fecha,
       nomentidad,
       convenio,
       tdoc,
       paciente,
       nompaciente,
       apellidos,
       nombres,
       sexo,
       recibo,
       autoriz,
       edad,
       f_nacimiento,
       cargo,
       empresa_temporal,
       carne,
       procedi,
       nomprocedi,
       SUM(valor)                               AS total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(nomprocedi SEPARATOR '| |') AS procedimiento
FROM   db
GROUP  BY paciente
ORDER  BY nompaciente
```

Comment: Tomen en cuenta que al no agrupar por el mismo número de columnas que se están seleccionando, se puede generar un error de sintaxis. [Favor de leer esta referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246736/new-version-of-php-mysql-got-an-aggregate-error-in-group-by-clause) antes de ocupar esta solución.